# Android studio Kotlin OnClickListerner function

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, onclicklistener

When I implemented the member in the class for the on click listener as shown below:

```
class QuizQuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
```

I was given the option of implementing it as:

```
 override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
```

I need it to be

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
```

can someone explain the difference and why I am not getting the option of `v: View`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin provide default parameter with alphabets and digits you can simply change it with your variable name like --

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) { }

override fun onClick(view: View?) { } 

override fun onClick(myView: View?) { }
```

It's quit good and it's meaningful variable name that remember as long time. where P0 and P1 named variable is not like good to remember.

**Hope You can understand what I mean to say.**

Answer (score 1):

Both of those functions are the same, it's just a different name for the `View` variable. Kotlin parameters are listed with the parameter name first, then the class name.

If you want `p0` to be `v` instead, just change the parameter name to be `v`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You have no idea how much I googled to try and find the answer.